# Update From in Toad/SQL Plus/10g

Tags: oracle10g

I know you're all waiting to hit the down arrow, since it seems as though this question gets answered near every day; however, it seems as though an update/from clause does not work with my particular configuration. The configuration I'm using is as it is in the title: Toad DB tool, SQL Plus editor, 10g machine. I return an error whether or not I add a from clause in the following snippet (note: I've checked that all of my column names are present and spelled correctly)

```
UPDATE distinct_network_point 
SET altitude = altitude_of_point.altitude 
FROM  altitude_of_point 
WHERE distinct_network_point.id= altitude_of_point.id
```

I want to update column 1 in a table from column 2 in another table where column 1 in table 1 is equal to column 1 in table 2. Is this possible with my configuration? I've also tried modifying a select subquery to this effect, but cannot get it to group properly.

Answer (score 0):

http://psoug.org/reference/update.html This was a very helpful lead, had just what I needed.